# Changing Bootstrap button text on toggle

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, toggle

I currently have a collapse button built with Bootstrap and I'm trying to transform the text from 'Read more' to 'Read less'. I've been trying jQuery, but I just can't get it to work.

```
<a data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseExample' id='#collapseExample' class='text-center btn btn-default'>Read More</a>
    <div class='collapse' id='collapseExample'>
        <p class='readmore'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#collapseExample').on('click', function () {
  var text=$('#collapseExample').val();
  if(text==='Read more'){
    $(this).text('Read less');
  } else{
    $(this).text('Read more');
 }
});
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Don't use same id twice in a html page that's invalid.
2. Don't start a id with `#` can cause a lot of problem while using in jquery.
3. The strings must match exactly so `Read more` won't work, you need to use `Read More`.
4. Don't use `val()` instead use `text()` or `html()`

**Working snppet**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#collapseExample1').on('click', function () {
  var text=$('#collapseExample1').text();
  if(text === "Read More"){
    $(this).html('Read less');
  } else{
    $(this).text('Read More');
 }
});
});
```

```html
<a data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseExample' id='collapseExample1' class='text-center btn btn-default'>Read More</a>
    <div class='collapse' id='collapseExample2'>
        <p class='readmore'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do set up a variable called `toggled` wich has a boolean value `true/false`. Then you can check if the link is clicked or not. For example:

jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var btn = $("[href='#collapseExample']");
    var toggled = false;
    btn.on("click", function() {
        if(!toggled)
        {
          toggled = true;
          btn.text("Read less");
        } else {
          toggled = false;
          btn.text("Read more");
        }
    });
});
```

And the link:

```
<a data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseExample' id='#collapseExample' class='text-center btn btn-default'>Read More</a>
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/8wmbzn28/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `text()` instead of `val()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#collapseExample').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#collapseExample').text();
        if (text==='Read more') {
            $(this).text('Read less');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Read more');
        }
    });
})
```